# Fuzzy image through HTDMI Fedora 25

Tags: linux, fedora, resolution, amd-graphics-card

I have Fedora 25 mate-desktop and ATI/AMD driver on my laptop. I have an external monitor with resolution 1920x1080. On my external monitor I have bad pixel resolution. How to fix it?

Display `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080     60.01 +  40.00  
  1680x1050     60.00  
  1400x1050     60.00  
  1280x1024     59.95  
  1440x900      59.99  
  1280x960      59.99  
  1280x854      59.95  
  1280x800      59.96  
  1280x720      59.97  
  1152x768      59.95  
  1024x768      59.95  
  800x600       59.96  
  848x480       59.94  
  720x480       59.94  
  640x480       59.94  
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x  axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.01    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And

```
 lspci  | grep VGA -A 12

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]  Device 98e4 (rev ea)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157a
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI    Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
```

My monitor is BenQ EW2750ZL and laptop is HP 255 G6 2HG34ES.

Comment: This is image https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Puno.png

Comment: Is the monitor connected via VGA or HDMI? Is there an HDMI to VGA adaptor involved?

Comment: Monitor connected via HDMI. No